# Modal View Controller unable to use Constraints

Tags: swift, uiview, constraints, modalviewcontroller

I have a XIB with some content 
[image]

Let's say it has a label and I want to place constraints on all edges such that the size of the view effectively becomes the label.

I would then like to present it in a modal. In this case it would be a label with a grey background. How would I do this using constraints. I know you can use something with preferredContentSize, but I want to avoid that as in my actual view I have dozens of constraints that depend on each other and I don't want to add them together every time. Right now, it is just using the frame size (whatever it says in the XIB) as the view container which is also a bad solution.

How do I do this? Is there a better way around it?

Comment: i don't quite understand what you are saying. what do you actually want to achieve in the first place?

Comment: Have the view shrink to size of label